# How to animate the width and height of an ellipse in an UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I'm trying to animate the width and height property of an `Ellipse` element in XAML. I found a few examples online, but none of them seems to work.
I'm sure I'm missing only something little and stupid. Here my animation in xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="PressFormLogin" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="259.0" To="149.0" Duration="0:0:5" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="259.0" To="149.0" Duration="0:0:5" />
    </Storyboard>
 </Page.Ressources>
```

The `Ellipse` element in XAML:

```
<Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse"  Width="259" Height="259" Fill="#FF5AA1BA" />
```

And how I try to start the animation in the code behind:

```
PressFormLogin.Begin();
```

It's the first time that I'm using a animation in one of my applications, it would be nice if someone could give me a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` for your `DoubleAnimation`. See [EnableDependentAnimation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.enabledependentanimation?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: It's better to not use DependentAnimation set to true. Instead it's better to use RenderTransform and animate Scale.X and Scale.Y

Comment: @MichalKania can you explain why shouldn't use EnableDependentAnimation?

Comment: @NghiaNghia Quotation from the link above: "Use this property with caution, because setting it to true means you are deliberately acknowledging that the animation might slow down other operations on the UI thread when it runs."